# Узнать количество членов enum

Tags: c++

Как узнать количество членов `enum`?

Пусть в классе задаю `enum`: `enum a{a1,a2,a3,a4,a5};`, а в другом классе есть метод, который перебирает значения вектора по членам `a` с помощью `for(int...)`. Но если я потом увеличу количество членов `a`, то придется менять это и в методе. И хотелось бы задавать размер вектора от размера `a`.

Или узнать какой элемент последний.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Узнать кол-во констант в перечислении не представляется возможным. Если вы используете проход по циклу, то может быть достаточно просто задать константу, говорящую о максимальном размере. Ну, или если всё же хочется иметь именованные константы, то можно в `enum` задать последний элемент как `aMax`:

```
enum A { a1, a2, a3 ... , aMax };
```

Цикл в таком случае будет выглядеть так:

```
for( A v = a1; v < aMax; ++v ) { ... }
```

Добавлю, что вся эта схема работает, только при отсутствии разрывов в значениях перечисления. Например:

```
enum A { a1, a2 = 100, a3 ... , aMax };
```

породит проблему отсутствия значений в диапазоне [1..99]. Т.е. цикл должен как-то это учитывать, а не идти обычным инкрементом.