# Имеется ли число в enum

Tags: c++, enum

Программа читает число с flash-памяти внешнего устройства (целое, 1 байт, беззнаковое). Для его программной интерпретации используется перечисление:

```
enum BoardType {
    Classic = 0,
    Static = 1,
    Smart = 2
}
BoardType t = (BoardType)getBoardType();
```

Проблема видна невооружённым взглядом: число, содержащееся в памяти, не обязательно содержится в enum. И я думаю, что в runtime никак не проверить, корректно ли возвращённое число, а оно будет обязательно, ведь во flash-памяти в стёртом состоянии хранятся значения 0xFF, а также могут попадать другие числа, которые оказались там из-за моих кривых рук. Итак, есть ли способ проверить, содержится ли возвращённое число в enum, а если нет, то как правильно программно интерпретировать это число?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Узнать количество членов enum](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/545118/%d0%a3%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-%d1%87%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2-enum)

Comment: @alexolut, значения перечисления не обязательно идут по порядку. К тому же, я упомянул, что подозреваю, что это невозможно, поэтому хотел бы увидеть альтернативные варианты.

Comment: В упомянутой теме как раз решение для Вашего вопроса озвучено. Т.е. если диапазон непрерывный, то можно проверить граничные точки, а если с "дырами", то всё усложняется.

Comment: Не занимайтесь ерундой. Enum-ы просто изначально предназначены для другого.

Comment: @avp, не бросайтесь словами. Enum предназначены для другого? Тогда расскажите, что использовать вместо них в данной ситуации. Пока я вижу ответ Majestio главным кандидатом на "галочку".

Comment: Обычный `uint8_t`, если не хотите кучи лишнего кода с сопутствующим геморроем. Впрочем, почти все учатся только на своих ошибках.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я бы предложил, коль речь идет о быстродействии и небольшом количестве команд - использовать просто табличные преобразования. Да и таблица не будет чрезмерно большой.

Пример кода ([ссылка на ideone](http://ideone.com/zssHpQ)):

```
#include <iostream>

enum class BoardType : uint8_t { 
  Classic = 0,
  Static = 1,
  Smart = 2,
  Bad = 255  
};

BoardType Cast[UINT8_MAX];     // <- сюда просто забить константы -++
                                                                   //
inline BoardType ToEnum(const uint8_t i) {                         //
  BoardType Ret = Cast[i];                                         //
  if (Ret == BoardType::Bad) throw std::range_error("Беда");       //
  return Ret;                                                      //
}                                                                  //
                                                                   //
int main () {                                                      //
  ////// вместо  инициализации ниже - ///////////////////////////////  
  for(auto i=0; i<UINT8_MAX; i++) Cast[i] = BoardType::Bad;
  Cast[0] = BoardType::Classic;
  Cast[1] = BoardType::Static;
  Cast[2] = BoardType::Smart; 
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  
  try {  
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(ToEnum(0)) << std::endl;  
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(ToEnum(1)) << std::endl;
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(ToEnum(2)) << std::endl;
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(ToEnum(3)) << std::endl;  
  } catch(std::range_error &e) {
    std::cout << "range_error: " << e.what() << std::endl;  
  } catch(...) {
    std::cout << "что-то совсем пошло не так" << std::endl;  
  }    
  return 0;        
}
```

Вывод:

```
0
1
2
range_error: Беда
```

Во-первых, можно с помощью функции `ToEnum()` "неправильные" значения отлавливать в блоках обработки исключений.

Во-вторых, используя таблицу `Cast`, просто сравнивать с `BoardType::Bad`, если обработка исключений "напрягает".

В-третьих, если "команд" будет несколько десятков - `switch` будет хуже читаем, а возможно и медленнее обрабатываем.

Answer (score 5):

По большому счету, никак. Потому что это просто условные обозначения для целочисленных значений.
Так что если уж очень нужно - то либо проверять диапазон (если перечисления без "просветов", либо иметь отдельное множество значений и проверять на присутствие в нем.

*По-моему, так*. (с) Пух

Comment: Ну вы же эксперт по C++. Да разве совсем никак? На С++ стараются эмулировать рефлексию уже давно. К примеру, как в ответах [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801363/c-c-any-way-to-get-reflective-enums) разве не получится?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Во-первых, чем это *по сути* отличается от сказанного мною? Во-вторых, знаете, бывают люди, которые пишут всякие `#define begin {` и начинают делать из C++ Pascal. Стоит ли? И главное - не надо спрашивать, как лучше держать микроскоп, чтобы забивать гвозди. Надо решать задачу наиболее подходящими для этого средствами.

Comment: Хорошо, а не существует ли красивого обходного пути? Допустим использовать другую структуру данных вроде какого-то "словаря" и т. д. Как бы вы решили проблему если надо хранить множество и проверять наличие элемента в нём?

Comment: Если множество мелкое - вектор или массив (упорядоченный, если есть информация, что ищем чаще), если побольше - вероятно, `set` или `unordered_set`. Возможно, с собственным хэшем. Если это множество без промежутков - просто сравнением. Но вы опять задаете не тот вопрос... Например, так, как сформулировано у автора - то скорее всего, его программная интерпретация будет использовать какой-то `switch` - а там достаточно написать `default`.

Answer (score 5):

Конкретно для вашего примера можно так:

```
enum BoardType{
    Classic = 0,
    Static = 1,
    Smart = 2,
    NumberOfBoardTypes
};

bool isCorrect(BoardType t){
    return t >= 0 && t < NumberOfBoardTypes;
}
```

Или так:

```
enum BoardType{
    Classic = 0,
    Static = 1,
    Smart = 2,
    Unknown
};

BoardType getBoardType(){
    BoardType t = static_cast<BoardType>(42);

    if(t < 0 || t > Unknown){
        t = Unknown;
    }

    return t;
}
```

**UPD:** для случая с "дырами" в `enum` можно сделать так:

```
enum BoardType{
    Classic = 0,
    Static = 1,
    Smart = 2
};

std::set<BoardType> boardTypes(){
    std::set<BoardType> types;
    types.insert(Classic);
    types.insert(Static);
    types.insert(Smart);

    return types;
}

bool isCorrect(BoardType t){
    static const std::set<BoardType> types = boardTypes();
    return types.count(t);
}
```

Comment: Да, по-моему, раз есть перечисление, то скорее всего у него есть что-то типа `switch` или - раз всего байт - массив из соответствующих, скажем так, *интерпретаторов*. И можно вообще не проверять на вхождение в `enum`, а или написать `default`, или забить неверные записи массива интерпретаторов каким-то обработчиком... Словом, мне кажется, что опять поставлен вопрос не как забить гвоздь, а как для этого правильно держать микроскоп...

Comment: @Harry, человек явно работает с железом. Вполне может быть что это значение потом передается в аппаратуру.